# Replace conditional If statements

Tags: java, if-statement, javafx, polymorphism, factory

Need to instantiate multiple [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) instances for different machines like `resetCredentialsMachineOne`, `resetCredentialsMachineTwo` and so on. For each machine will have a `PauseTransition` instance creation code repeated as shown below. The `expireCredentialsForMachine()` resets the `Credentials` object so that Users are forced to re-login:

```
    resetCredentialsMachineOne = new PauseTransition(Duration.minutes(2));
    resetCredentialsMachineOne.setOnFinished(e -> expireCredentialsForMachine(machineOne));

    resetCredentialsMachineTwo = new PauseTransition(Duration.minutes(2));
    resetCredentialsMachineTwo.setOnFinished(e -> expireCredentialsForMachine(machineTwo));
    .....
```

When users login, will have the below `conditional` code for each `PauseTransition` instance:

```
if(machineOneLogsIn) 
resetCredentialsMachineOne.playFromStart();

else if(machineTwoLogsIn)
resetCredentialsMachineTwo.playFromStart();
...
```

Looking for a way to design the code in a better fashion rather than having bunch of if-statements. This appears like a polymorphism or a factory use-case but wanting to hear from others if they have any opinions on this

Comment: Could you add code with sample if-statements? Will help us to understand the question better.

Comment: @YogeshBadke Done!

Comment: Sounds like a mapping situation: you want to map the first transition to the first machine, and the second transition to the second machine. When the user logs in, give them an ID based on the machine (`0` for the first, `1` for the second), rather than flipping a `boolean`. Store the `PauseTransition` instances in an array, then access the instance based on the ID: `transitions[machineID].playFromStart()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at following class based on SOLID principles.

- It's open for extension but closed for modification,
- Abstracts the transition logic into the manager
- Decouples machine object and transition logic

```
public class MachinePauseTransitionManager {

    private static final Map<Machine, PauseTransition> MACHINE_PAUSE_TRANSITIONS = new HashMap<> ();

    public void createPauseTransition(Machine machine) {
        PauseTransition resetCredentialsMachine = new PauseTransition(Duration.minutes(2));
        resetCredentialsMachine.setOnFinished(e -> expireCredentialsForMachine(machine));
        MACHINE_PAUSE_TRANSITIONS.put(machine, resetCredentialsMachine)
    }

    public void login(Machine machine) {
        MACHINE_PAUSE_TRANSITIONS.get(machine).playFromStart();
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
MachinePauseTransitionManager manager = new MachinePauseTransitionManager();
Machine machineOne = ..
Machine machineTwo = ..

// creating pause transitions
manager.createPauseTransition(machineOne);
manager.createPauseTransition(machineTwo);
.
.
.
// when perticular machine logs in
manager.login(machineOne);
manager.login(machineTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure how your application is designed, personally I would design it something like this:

```
public class Machine {
    private final PauseTransition resetCredentials = new PauseTransition(Duration.minutes(2));

    public Machine() {
        resetCredentials.setOnFinished(e -> expireCredentials());
    }

    public final void logIn() {
        resetCredentials.playFromStart();
    }
    public final void expireCredentials() {
        // Your implementation
    }
    // Other things that you may need, e.g. credentialsExpired boolean field
}
```

Why this makes sense:

- Every machine has its own personal state that you need to track.
- Every machine can be logged in anyway.
- Every machine uses a `PauseTransition` to do a countdown of credential validity.

Instead of breaking all these things out and trying to mix and match, it's easier move them into a common class. Whether this class is a model or controller, it depends on how you modify from here. You can move the states into another model class, and let the logic remains as the controller.

Comment: I see your approach, all the code pasted is inside a JavaFX controller class

Answer (score 0):

Using enum it can be achieved easily.

from:

```
if(machineOneLogsIn) 
resetCredentialsMachineOne.playFromStart();
else if(machineTwoLogsIn)
resetCredentialsMachineTwo.playFromStart();
```

to:

```
enum LoginType {
  MachineOneLogsIn
  {
    @Override
    public void playFromStart() {
    ...
    }
}, 
  MachineTwoLogsIn
  {
    @Override
    public void playFromStart() {
    ...
    }
};

 public abstract void playFromStart();
```

}

```
method doPlay(LoginType type){
   type.playFromStart()
}
```

let me know it makes sense...

Comment: It makes sense however if you see my code snippet, there is no need to override playFromStart(). It's a method defined inside PauseTransition https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#playFromStart()